# Define my own headline

Tags: koma-script, headline

How can I define my own head i. e. so that on each pages appears the same at the top?
I want to use it for short documents (max. 5 pages) with a head as shown in the picture.

With the following I do not succeed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\def\makeheadline{
\noindent My name \quad \hfill MM.DD.YYYY
\vspace{5pt}
\hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt \relax

\begin{center}
\textbf{My Headline}
\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
Hello
\newpage
Page 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to have a look here https://www.ctan.org/topic/page-hf and there https://www.ctan.org/topic/headings, as your requirements may vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the headers of a KOMA-Script class, it's better to use `scrlayer-scrpage`, which is part of the bundle.

You can include your code in `\chead{...}`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}% make room for the header

\newcommand{\makeheadline}{% custom header
\normalfont
My name  \hfill MM.DD.YYYY
\vspace{1ex}
\hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt 
\vspace{1.5ex}
\textbf{My Headline}
}

\chead{\makeheadline}% custom header in the chead
\cfoot{Page~\thepage}% page numbering


\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \kant[1-14]
\end{document}
```

You can use the `fancyhdr` package and ignore the (long) warning. This code will produce a similar result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
    
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}% make room for the header

\newcommand{\makeheadline}{% custom header
    \normalfont
    My name  \hfill MM.DD.YYYY
    \vspace{1ex}
    \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt 
    \vspace{1.5ex}
    \textbf{My Headline}
}


\usepackage{fancyhdr} % added <<<<<
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\makeheadline}
\fancyfoot[C]{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}Page~\thepage}


\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \kant[1-14]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You second example has two `\documentclass…\begin{document}…\end{document}`. Because LaTeX stops loading with the first `\end{document}` the second one is wast.

Comment: @cabohah Thank you! Bad copy an paste :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard page style `myheadings`, which is intended for manual page headings (see the description of `\pagestyle` in Section 3.18 of either the [English](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) or the [German KOMA-Script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-de.pdf)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headlines=2.7]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\def\makeheadline{%
  My name\hfill MM.DD.YYYY\\
  \rule[1ex]{\linewidth}{.4pt}
  \centering
  \textbf{My Headline}
}

\markright{%
  \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\makeheadline}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: without headinclude]

For such a large header I would also use option `headinclude`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headlines=2.7,headinclude]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\def\makeheadline{%
  My name\hfill MM.DD.YYYY\\
  \rule[1ex]{\linewidth}{.4pt}
  \centering
  \textbf{My Headline}
}

\markright{%
  \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\makeheadline}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: with headinclude]

Note: There is an issue with `\centering` inside the definition when using a very outdated TeX installations (AFAIK before TeX Live 2019). To avoid the issue you can either update or use

```
\def\makeheadline{%
  My name\hfill MM.DD.YYYY\\
  \rule[1ex]{\linewidth}{.4pt}\\
  \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\textbf{My Headline}}
}
```

instead of

```
\def\makeheadline{%
  My name\hfill MM.DD.YYYY\\
  \rule[1ex]{\linewidth}{.4pt}
  \centering
  \textbf{My Headline}
}
```

The result it the same.

Comment: Here I get an error, e. g. for the second example: Line 14 "! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }."

Comment: @ubuntuuser With exactly my code? Should not happen and does not happen with an up-to-date TeX installation. It happens only with TeX Live before 2019 but not only with the second, but also with the first example. If you need compatibility to such old TeX installations you can replace `\centering\textbf{…}` by `\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\textbf{…}}`. However, I would recommend an update.

Comment: OK, I have TeX Live 2017, admittedly.

Comment: @ubuntuuser Very old! But see the modification for such outdated TeX installations at the end of my answer. It should work, but I cannot test it with TeX Live 2017, because the oldest TeX Live I've still installed is the last update of TeX Live 2018.